# What key differences should I be sure to cover when explaining how I study the Bible as a Catholic to my Episcopalian friend?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, bible, episcopal

A friend of mine was recently given a full Bible and asked if I could read through the book of Tobit with her.  When we discussed the details of doing this, it turned out one of the things she is hoping to learn is how to read the Bible the way I do as representative of the way the Church teaches people to read the Bible.  While flattering, this is also kinda a big responsibility and I want to make sure I do the best I can.  We're probably going to spend a lot of time discussing the differences in our approaches to Bible-reading, but I was hoping for an overview as sort of a place to start. Her church is [St. Alban's](http://www.stalbansarcata.org/), if that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure on the bible/exigesis tags.  I feel like probably one of them is appropriate but maybe not both.  If you feel like one of them is wrong and you are more familiar with the site than me than feel free to correct it (I know tags are a folksonomy but I don't feel appropriately cultured here yet to call myself a folk :P )

Comment: The Episcopal Church does not have am officially prescribed method for teaching reading of the Bible, and to the best of my knowledge, the Roman Catholic Church does not, either. The principal difference between the approaches of th Roman Catholic Church and the Episcopal Church as far as a study of the book of Tobit, though, is that the RC church considers Tobit to be scripture, and the Episcopal Church does not.

Comment: @brasshat We will be studying the book as scripture.  I am certain that the Church has official teachings regarding the Bible, how it is to be read, and how it is to be interpreted.  See, for example, [Divino Afflante Spiritu](http://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xii_enc_30091943_divino-afflante-spiritu.html).  While I think it reasonably possible that no generally highly regarded similar lexical work exists for Episcopalians, I am  sure that persons learning how to read the Bible from participating in an Episcopal parish will develop certain commonalities

Comment: I am unsure how a request for an overview of differences between a specific subset of the Episcopalian church and the Catholic Church as regards how the Bible is taught to be read is too broad.  If I had asked a broader question, 'what are the key differences between Episcopalian and Catholic doctrines', the question would not have been closed, yes?

Comment: @thedarkwanderer I think it would take someone who has led Bible studies at both to appreciate the subtle differences in approach.  (I am scratching my head, to be honest with you, but I don't know anything about how the Episcopal church teaches bible study to be of any use to you).

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Yeah, that's what I think as well.  I've not lead Bible studies at both so I figured I'd ask here and hope for a response from someone who has.